# pytest throws error: "Requirements are missing the test case"

Tags: python, pytest

I tried to see how `nydok` combines specification and testing, following an example provided in `nydok` Github repository.

My `cowsay.spec.md` file looks like:

```
# Cowsay functional specification

## Functional requirements

- REQ001: The program must take as input a text string
- REQ002: The program must return a string with a cow in ASCII art, displaying the input text as a speech bubble
```

and `test_cowsay.py` file:

```
from nydok import testcase
import cowsay


@testcase(["REQ001", "REQ002"])
def test_cowsay():
    assert cowsay("Hello world") == """
     _____________
    < Hello world >
     -------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
    """
```

Running  py.test:

`> PS C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\MyPython\Specifications> py.test --nydok-output nydok.json cowsay.spec.md`

throws an error:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\MyPython\Specifications
plugins: nydok-0.8.3
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                 

cowsay.spec.md FF                                                                                                                          [100%] 

FAILURES 
RequirementTest: REQ001 The program must take as input a text string ______________________________________ 
Requirement REQ001 (C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\MyPython\Specifications\cowsay.spec.md:5) is missing test case:

@testcase("REQ001")
def test_the_program_must_take_as_input_a_text():
    raise NotImplementedError("To be implemented")

RequirementTest: REQ002 The program must return a string with a cow in ASCII art, displaying the input text as a speech bubble _________ 
Requirement REQ002 (C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\MyPython\Specifications\cowsay.spec.md:6) is missing test case:

@testcase("REQ002")
def test_the_program_must_return_a_string_with_a():
    raise NotImplementedError("To be implemented")

=============================================================== warnings summary 
..\..\..\..\..\Python39\lib\site-packages\nydok\plugin\plugin.py:46
  C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\nydok\plugin\plugin.py:46: PytestRemovedIn8Warning: The (fspath: py.path.local) argument to SpecFile is deprecated. Please use the (path: pathlib.Path) argument instead.
  See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#fspath-argument-for-node-constructors-replaced-with-pathlib-path
    return SpecFile.from_parent(parent, fspath=path)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
============================================================ short test summary info 
FAILED cowsay.spec.md::REQ001
FAILED cowsay.spec.md::REQ002
```

I cannot understand what is wrong with my spec. and test.
Appreciate any comment.

I expected to see:

```
cowsay/test_cowsay.py::test_cowsay PASSED                       [ 33%]
cowsay/cowsay.spec.md::REQ001 PASSED                            [ 66%]
cowsay/cowsay.spec.md::REQ002 PASSED                            [100%]
```